# Search NSString except substring has specific pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have NSString: `@"[ta hc]adf [bcd][qermaf[asdf]] bcd"` and pattern: `@"\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]"`

How to search string `@"bcd"`, but only search with substring not in my pattern. For above example I want to **only** find "bcd" at the end of string?

Comment: first explain why you want match `bcd` and not `ta hc` or `asdf`. Is your input string have constant format?

Comment: I don't want to search on [ta hc] [bcd] [asdf] which has pattern, thanks Marek R.